# How to initialize root store in angular-redux/store for testing?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, redux, angular-redux

I want to set the initial root Store for angular redux instead of calling `getSelectorStub` for one selector at a time. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[`StoreModule.forRoot()`](https://ngrx.io/api/store/StoreModule) contains an optional configuration object as input parameter.

```
 StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
      initialState: {} // <---- provide initial state
 }
```